# Customized loss function in PyTorch which uses DNN outputs and additional variables

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, loss-function, dnn9

(I am sorry if my English is not good)

I can create my own loss function in PyTorch if the function requires only DNN output vector(predicted) and DNN output vector(ground truth).

I want to use additional variables to calculate the loss.

I make my training and test data like below;

**DNN input:**

1. `Data_A` -> processing 1 -> `Data_X`

**DNN output:**

2. `Data_A` -> processing 1 -> `Data_X`
3. `Data_B` -> processing 1 -> `Data_P`
4. `Data_X` , `Data_P` -> processing 2 -> `Data_Y`

and I divide `Data_X` and `Data_Y` into train data and test data.
`x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Data_X,Data_Y,test_size=0.2, random_state=0)`

I want to use `Data_A`, `Data_B`, `Data_Y(predicted)`, and `Data_Y(ground truth)` to calculate the loss.
I saw many examples for customized loss function which only use `Data_Y(predicted)` and `Data_Y(ground truth)`. I could use such a customized loss function before.
However, I don't know what to do when I want to use another additional variables.
Is there a good way? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your naming is a bit confusing and your question seems very broad: you have two models and use outputs from the first one to feed the second one. You want to compute a loss (what loss?) based on the inputs from `Data_A` and `Data_B`, the output of the model, and the ground truth. You can implement such a function, yes. However, without further details it's hard to help.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I see, I will show further details. `Data_A` and `Data_B` are complex vectors.  `Processing 1` is `torch.abs()`. Therefore `Data_X = torch.abs(Data_A)` and `Data_P = torch.abs(Data_B)`. `Processing 2` consists of `torch.pow()` and  `torch.div()`. In detail, `Data_Y = torch.div(torch.pow(torch.abs(Data_A),2), torch.pow(torch.abs(Data_B),2)`. The DNN input is `Data_X`. The DNN output is `Data_Y`. I want to calculate the loss by  `torch.mean(torch.pow(Data_Y * Data_A - Data_B ,2))`.

Comment: As long as you use PyTorch operators you should be fine, see Shai's answer below to create a custom loss function.

Comment: OK. I try to creats a custom function. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no restrictions over the structure of your loss function (as long as the gradients make sense).
For instance, you can have:

```py
class MyLossLayer(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyLossLayer, self).__init__()

  def forward(self, pred_a, pred_b, gt_target):
    # I'm just guessing here - do whatever you want as long as you do not screw the gradients.
    loss = pred_a * (pred_b - target)
    return loss.mean()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! I see. Actually I want to do like this; `Data_A` and `Data_B` are complex vectors.  `Processing 1` is `torch.abs()`. Therefore `Data_X = torch.abs(Data_A)` and `Data_P = torch.abs(Data_B)`. `Processing 2` consists of `torch.pow()` and  `torch.div()`. In detail, `Data_Y = torch.div(torch.pow(torch.abs(Data_A),2), torch.pow(torch.abs(Data_B),2)`. The DNN input is `Data_X`. The DNN output is `Data_Y`. I want to calculate the loss by  `torch.mean(torch.pow(Data_Y * Data_A - Data_B ,2))`.

Comment: If I try to do like this in your code,  `pred_a` is DNN output while `gt_target` is DNN ground truth output, and `pred_b1` is an additional variables which is equal to `Data_A`, `pred_b2` is also an additional variables which is equal to `Data_B`, And `loss = torch.mean(torch.pow(pred_a * pred_b1 - *pred_b2 ,2))`.

Comment: And in this case, I have a question about additional variables. I think I don't have to care about `pred_a` or `gt_target`, they are given to the loss function as usual. However, when I use additional variables, I need to feed them to the loss function by hand. However, in the training session, loss function is calculated by batch by batch. I wonder how I know which data (index) is chosen to the current batch. Do you have any ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: I use your code and it works!! Thank you very much.